# IIS 7.5 - Friendly URL for Web SIte

Tags: iis-7.5

I am running IIS 7.5 and back-end of a web application. This web app is only accessible from within the intranet. 
Currently it can be accessed as http://f97fa43fa - some combination of letters and numbers. I would like to create a more friendly name for the web site.
How do I do that? Thanks.

PS - I tried the redirect feature, but it did not work.

Comment: Ask your network administrators and set up DNS accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but there no network admin, it is all me.

Comment: Then you cannot fulfill the task without learning the necessary bits. Hints are, 1) know what DNS server is used and set it up with a domain name you like. 2) point that domain to the IP address of this IIS server. 3) configure site binding to serve traffic from that domain name. Jexus Manager might help in certain aspects, https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html but most of the work requires you to learn computer network basics.

Comment: Thanks, I am conversant with network basics. I knew what you meant when you referred to update DNS server with the desired name. But was looking for a workaround. I cannot expect IT to do anything for me.